# Execute browser extension in about:config

Tags: javascript, json, firefox-addon, browser-extension

I am currently working on a browser extension which is supposed to run a script once you open the Firefox settings.

I already tried to include about:config in the match property of my manifest.json file and I tried to find a solution online with no success.

Here is the code so far:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version":2,
  "version":"1.0",
  "name":"Test",
  "content_scripts":[
    {
     "matches":["about:preferences"],
     "js":["main.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

main.js:

```
alert("The test extension is up and running.")
```

The code would otherwise work on other pages when the match property is set to "<all_urls>".

Comment: This is probably disallowed for security reasons.

Comment: Given the "solution" you edited into your question, it appears your question is unclear. Your question currently asks to run a content script **in** the "about:config" page, which is a duplicate of the current duplicate target. The "solution" which you edited into your question appears to indicate that you want to know *in your background script* that the active tab is currently displaying the "about:config" page in order to run code *in your background script*. Those are two **very different** questions. If the latter is what you're really wanting, then please [edit] your question to say so.

Comment: If that's *really* what you're wanting and you edit your question to make that clear, then I'm happy to reopen this question (although, I'll have to look around to see if it's a duplicate of different questions than the current duplicate target).

Comment: I've rolled back your edit adding an answer in your Question. I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your Question. In general, you should [edit] the Question to *clarify the Question*, but not to include an Answer within the Question. You should create your own Answer with the code you used to solve your problem, then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to accepting your own Answer). When you've solved the problem yourself, [posting an answer to your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).

Comment: If you want the Markdown for your question prior to my rolling it back, you can find a [link to the source for that version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/decc89e1-d035-4497-85c5-4f2d4b0311fd/view-source) on the question's [revisions page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76243963/revisions).